# How to export KIE-WB databases to another database engine as MySQL?

Tags: drools, jbpm, drools-guvnor, kie

I have an installation of Drools kie-wb 6.1.0. By default, it works with Derby database and now, I want to move it to a production environment (where MySQL server is used). How can I export the database from one engine to other?

All information found in the official documentation seems to be from Guvnor, that has some specifics options in the menu "Administration" in the tab called "Repository Configuration". But in KIE-WB there I only can define new repositories (by GIT or SSH). Is something missing in my installation? or the option is elsewhere?

Comment: As far as I was aware, all rules in Workbench should now be stored in a Git repo, rather than a database. I'm not certain, but I think that references to Derby may be copy-paste bugs from the older 5.x 'Guvnor' docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as @Steve says, it must be a documentation error. Now I understand deeply Drools and I see that database is only used for internal application management, not for rules or projects. Then, in my case, there is not need to move to MySQL.